# How to move (large) files between file systems in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons

In my Java 7 application I need to move all files and directories in the `sourceFolder` to another `destinationFolder`. I do not know whether these two folders are on the same file system or partition, as both can be specified by the user at runtime.

Since the files and directories to move can be quite large (some GB), I was searching for an efficient way of moving them. So they should only be copied if `sourceFolder` and `destinationFolder` are not on the same file system. So ideally the move operation on the same file system should rather be a rename operation, if possible.

The application is used on both Windows and Linux systems.

I know about some [related Java 7 functionalities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), however, they do not allow to move all contents of a folder to somewhere else if it is not empty, which is a requirement in my case. I also found [Apache Common's FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class, which looks promising. However, its documentation says one should do a *"copy and delete"* operation if `sourceFolder` and `destinationFolder` are not on the same file system.

So my question is: When I use that `FileUtils` class, how can I then check the file systems of `sourceFolder` and `destinationFolder` in a cross-platform manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to `FileUtils.moveFile()`.

The `moveFile` *takes care* of the case where the source and destination are on different directories.  What it does is to try to use `File.renameTo`, and if that fails, it tries to copy the file.  (See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.moveFile%28java.io.File,java.io.File%29).)  In short, *you* don't need to check for yourself ...

But in response to your actual question, neither `File` or Apache `FileUtils`
 provides a way to *test* if two directories are on the same file system.  But (I think) you can do it using Java 7 functionality by something like this:

```
Path path1 = new File(str1).toPath();
Path path2 = new File(str2).toPath();
if (path1.getFileSystem().equals(path2.getFileSystem()) {
    ...
```

Comment: @Matthias Note that `FileSystem` doesn't represent different disks.

Comment: This should work on Windows, but I'm not so sure about a Unix filesystem.